# Makefile internal command on linux functional but not macos

Tags: makefile

Within a Makefile on linux, we can excute shell/bash commands with it to move directories or excute another files. However when porting the same Makefile over to macOS, all the commands are not readible (therefore path and execution are broken). Is there a universal command or workflow that can work on both?

Example of Makefile

```
.ONESHELL:

COMMAND ?= none
GIT_HASH ?= githash

alpine:
    @cd images/alpine

    @make ${COMMAND} GIT_HASH=${GIT_HASH} ALPINE_VERSION=3.6.5 TAG=3.6
```

so in a linux box both @CD and @MAKE are executed but not for macOS Catalina. I would like to make it universal so that both system will respect the appropriate command that follows.

Comment: Try combining cd and make lines to: `make -C <dir> <args>`; posted version might work if preceded with  `.ONESHELL:` and without the blank line

Comment: @Milag it was already on `.ONESHELL;` and macOS is not interpreting it.

Comment: OK, `.ONESHELL` now visible after your update. What is your version of  `make` on macOS?  Experiment: add 2 lines with `echo $$$$`; pids are same or different?

Comment: Chances are that your MacOS box uses its default GNU make version (3.81). Don't know why Apple insists in using such an old version but `.ONESHELL` was introduced with 3.82. Upgrade with Homebrew or MacPort. Anyway, better avoid `make` in recipes, prefer `$(MAKE)`, and instead of `cd; make` you can use GNU make's `-C` option: `$(MAKE) -C images/alpine ...`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet so your recommendations are to upgrade the GNU and instead of having multiple make files just have a giant one and use relative path to operate on?

Comment: Apple will never ship a newer version of GNU make or a newer version of Bash or a newer version of any GNU/FSF program than what they ship today and have shipped for the last 5+ years, because the versions they ship are the last versions released under the GPLv2 and they would rather burden their users with old buggy software than ship GPLv3 software.

Comment: No one is suggesting _have a giant [makefile]_.  Using the `-C` option simply performs the same `cd` operation but in one step rather than two different comments.  See the GNU make manual to learn what the `-C` option does.

Comment: @MadScientist Interesting, I will try to understand why GPLv3 disgusts Apple more than GPLv2. Not sure I'll succeed, though, these companies are a bit obscure to me.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet your explanation of 3.81 -> upgrade higher (did it through brew) solved the issue. As the one that gave the solution, please write it as such so i can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that your MacOS box uses its default GNU make version (3.81). `.ONESHELL` was introduced with 3.82. Upgrade with Homebrew or MacPort. Anyway, better avoid `make` in recipes, prefer `$(MAKE)`, and instead of `cd; make` you can use GNU make's `-C` option: `$(MAKE) -C images/alpine ...`

Comment: for those on macOS: `brew install make`, then adding the path to your `.bashrc` will fix the issue instead of doing the -c make.